# Add data dynamically to table when Floating Action Button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift3, scroll, floating-action-button, dynamic-columns

I have a `scrollView` (subclassed from custom `UITableView()`) which has number of rows and columns and scrolls in horizontal and vertical direction. I have to add data **dynamically** to the scrollView when **floating action button** is pressed.

**UPDATED:** I was able to display the dynamic data successfully in rows and columns. But I don't want to load my scrollView with all the dynamic data upon scroll, because data is too large to handle. Instead, I have to display only 5 columns initially and when **user presses the floating action button**, data should get added to rows and columns dynamically again with a count of 5 columns and 'x' rows.

I am stuck in adding dynamic data to scrollView when floating action button is pressed. Also how to show only 5 columns initially and add more 5*n columns when floating action button is pressed.

Any Suggestion or Help is much appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a CollectionView which has build-in horizontal scrolling support instead of a custom TableView.

For the "floating action button" I would suggest to create a separate view that has a label that tells the user to release to load more items and moves in when the user reaches the end of the scrollView. In the following example the load more view has a width of 100px and suggest that user releases his finger after dragging the view 85px.

**Swift 3**

```
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var loadMoreView: UIView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var loadMoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var loadMoreConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width {
        loadMoreView.isHidden = false
        loadMoreLabel.text = "Load more"
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width) - scrollView.contentSize.width > 85 {
            loadMoreLabel.text = "Release"
        }

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width) - scrollView.contentSize.width < 100 {
            loadMoreConstraint.constant = 100 - ((scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width) - scrollView.contentSize.width)
        }
    } else {
        loadMoreView.isHidden = true
        loadMoreConstraint.constant = 100
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width) - scrollView.contentSize.width > 85 {
            // TODO: <Load more logic here>
        }
    }
}
```

The load more view has the following constraints, where the "Align Trailing" constraint is linked with the loadMoreConstraint IBOutlet in the code above.

[image]

Comment: I did locking the scrollView part. Thank you. Only the action button press functionality isn't done. I am not able to reload data on click of floating button... instead data gets refreshed